# Installing PHP MySQLi extension creates .ini file only and MySQLi.so module no found

Tags: php, mysqli, centos

Hello pls I tried to install php-mysqli on Cent Os 7.
After installing only the mysqli.ini file that enables the module is installed.
I cannot find the mysqli.so file. in module folder.
PHP cannot find the module.
PHP version 7.2, Cent Os 7, MySQL 8

Comment: How does the stub ini look? Where have you looked for the .so module? Tried reinstalling the package (verbosely)? File list of package contents? `phpinfo()`/`php -i` output? (If it's just about installation, this borders on not being a programming question, btw.)

Comment: PD of [Cannot install php-mysqli extension on Centos](//stackoverflow.com/q/21272748) / [How to install MySQLi](//stackoverflow.com/q/7250356) / [Unable to install php-mysqli on PHP7](//stackoverflow.com/q/36387338) (at least for examples on how to provide more useful details).